# How to value a DTD variable inside CDATA section?

Tags: xml, dtd, cdata, entities

I have an XML that looks like the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd" 
    [<!ENTITY IP_COF "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">]
>
<properties>
   <comment>Properties for COF API</comment>
   <entry key="SesameURL">http://&IP_COF;:8080/openrdf-sesame</entry>
   <entry key="RDbNamespaces">
       <![CDATA[PREFIX vocab: <http://&IP_COF;:2020/vocab/resource/>]]>
   </entry>
</properties>
```

When I open the xml file using internet explorer the first instace of `&IP_COF;` is correctly replaced with the correspondent `IP_COF` value, instead the `IP_COF` inside the `CDATA` section has not been valued. Is there a way to force also the `IP_COF` valutation inside the `CDATA`'s section?

Answer (score 3):

No - the whole point of CDATA sections is that the parser will *not* alter them.

If you want to use entity expansions there, you'll need to remove the CDATA, and corectly encode the URL, i.e.

```
<entry key="RDbNamespaces">
   PREFIX vocab: &lt;http://&IP_COF;:2020/vocab/resource/&gt;
</entry>
```